# liferay workflow configuration mail template

Tags: email, templates, workflow, liferay-6

does any body know how to change  mail template in life ray work flow configuration.
I have tried by searching work flow configurations in control panel, but i dint find any solution over there.My requirement is need to change the mail body, subject and from address in that mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look under package `\portal-impl\src\com\liferay\portlet\journal\dependencies\`
you would get mail templates being used for it.
To change them, you have to use plugin-ext.